# Data Table Information not Populating to all Data Grid View's in Loop

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview, datatables

I've created an application that's reading workstation DNS names and pinging them to see if there are any workstations that are having network connectivity issues.

Everything is great up until the end, where I'm trying to read in the Output file information and display it in `DataGridView` (DGV).

The issue occurs when I'm trying to display the code created datatable from the read text file and populate different DataGridViews. It works fine with a single room selected. But when I try and output the data to multiple DataGridViews, only the *last* DataGridView is populated with it's data. None of the previous DGV's are populated.

A little more information, I have a TabControl with TabPages that correspond to each room, in those TabPages are where each separate DataGridView resides. So in total there are 12 DataGridViews that *could* need a datatables information assign to it's DataSource.

I've tried simply adding the data via DGV.Rows.Add() [this isn't actual code, just an explanation]. Now while this worked fine for outputting the information to the DataGridView with a single selection, I could not find a way to clear the DataGridView when I was simply adding Row Data to it. `DGV<Name>.Rows.Clear()` did nothing, `DGV<Name>.Rows.Remove(#)` erred out, `DGV<Name>.DataSource = VbNull` did nothing either, and I'm assuming that's because with that method I actually wasn't adding a datasource to the DGV in the first place.

Any assistance as to what I need to do to make sure that each Room's DGV has it's output information correctly in it's appropriate DGV would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using VS 2015 Community Edition if that makes any difference. And I do not have access to the LINQ plugin, just in-case people were thinking that might be a way to solve it.

Here's the associated code:

```
    Private Sub loadResults()

    Dim i As Integer = 0        'Counter variable
    Dim fName As String() = GlobalVariables.selectedRoomsList.ToArray
    Dim x As Integer = fName.Length         'Upper limit of the Array to be checked against
    Dim AppDir As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.StartupPath))
    Dim dataName As String = "dgv" & fName(i)
    Dim resultFilePath As String = AppDir & "\data\output\" & fName(i) & ".txt"
    Dim fileExists As Boolean = File.Exists(resultFilePath)
    Dim rowvalue As String
    Dim cellvalue(5) As String
    Dim oDataTable As DataTable

    lblGoodPingTotal.Text = GlobalVariables.successfulPings
    lblBadPingTotal.Text = GlobalVariables.failedPings
    lblTimeElapsed.Text = GlobalVariables.elapsedTime

    Do Until i > x

        oDataTable = New DataTable("PingTable")

        Dim Column1 As DataColumn = New DataColumn("Computer Name")
        Column1.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
        Dim Column2 As DataColumn = New DataColumn("Status")
        Column2.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
        Dim Column3 As DataColumn = New DataColumn("IP Address")
        Column3.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
        Dim Column4 As DataColumn = New DataColumn("Bytes Sent")
        Column4.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
        Dim Column5 As DataColumn = New DataColumn("Round Trip")
        Column5.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
        Dim Column6 As DataColumn = New DataColumn("TTL")
        Column6.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")

        oDataTable.Columns.Add(Column1)
        oDataTable.Columns.Add(Column2)
        oDataTable.Columns.Add(Column3)
        oDataTable.Columns.Add(Column4)
        oDataTable.Columns.Add(Column5)
        oDataTable.Columns.Add(Column6)

        If fileExists Then

            Using sReader As New StreamReader(resultFilePath)

                While sReader.EndOfStream = False

                    Dim rowAdd As DataRow
                    rowAdd = oDataTable.NewRow()

                    rowvalue = sReader.ReadLine()
                    cellvalue = rowvalue.Split(","c)

                    rowAdd.ItemArray = cellvalue

                    oDataTable.Rows.Add(rowAdd)

                End While

                sReader.Close()

            End Using

            dataPrint(dataName, oDataTable)

            i = i + 1

        Else
            MsgBox("Error! The file for Room" & fName(i) & "is not found.", vbOKOnly = MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")

            Exit Do

        End If

    Loop

End Sub

Private Sub dataPrint(iName As String, iTableData As DataTable)

    Dim dgvName As String = iName
    Dim oDataTable As DataTable = iTableData

    If dgvName = "dgvA1402" Then

        dgvA1402.DataSource = oDataTable

    ElseIf dgvName = "dgvA1532" Then

        dgvA1532.DataSource = oDataTable

    ElseIf dgvName = "dgvA1D038" Then

        dgvA1D038.DataSource = oDataTable

    ElseIf dgvName = "dgvA1D042" Then

        dgvA1D042.DataSource = oDataTable

    ElseIf dgvName = "dgvA1D043B" Then

        dgvA1D043B.DataSource = oDataTable

    ElseIf dgvName = "dgvA1E014A" Then

        dgvA1E014A.DataSource = oDataTable

    ElseIf dgvName = "dgvA1E036" Then

        dgvA1E036.DataSource = oDataTable

    ElseIf dgvName = "dgvA1E047C" Then

        dgvA1E047C.DataSource = oDataTable

    ElseIf dgvName = "dgvA1E047D" Then

        dgvA1E047D.DataSource = oDataTable

    ElseIf dgvName = "dgvA1E047F" Then

        dgvA1E047F.DataSource = oDataTable

    ElseIf dgvName = "dgvA1E047G" Then

        dgvA1E047G.DataSource = oDataTable

    ElseIf dgvName = "dgvA1E048" Then

        dgvA1E048.DataSource = oDataTable

    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: You create one data source oDataTable, and constantly redefine (by New) it for the next room. So only the last room has data. You should create a new copy of the data for each room.

Comment: I thought about that and tried making the oDatatable into an array, so something like:
Dim oDataTable(x) as DataTable
But this didn't see to work and actually resulted in nothing being displayed to any of the DataGridViews. Is there a way to loop through this with each text file?
Would setting the Tables name property to a variable (that changes) be enough or do I need an actual new instance of the "As DataTable" object?

Comment: Try to create a user control based upon a tab page which contains a datasource, a datagrid (linked to datasource) and any other controls you need for this ":room". Then use your data to generate one of these for each room and add it to the tab control TabControl.Controls.Add(). The tab will  be self contained with its own datasource. And you only have code for the room, in one place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'd like to say thank you to Marc Lyon for responding. However, I don't think I took your way to producing the answer I found.

But after doing some research and then a lot of trial and error the following code is what I came up with that works completely and gives me the output I was looking for. There's probably a shorter way of achieving the answer, but for now this works.

```
Private Sub loadResults(aRooms As List(Of String), pingUp As Integer, pingDown As Integer)
    '//All passed variables
    Dim rmNames As List(Of String) = aRooms
    '//All file path and directory variables
    Dim AppDir As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.StartupPath))
    Dim resultFilePath As String
    Dim fileExists As Boolean
    '//All row and row data variables
    Dim rowvalue As String
    Dim cellvalue(5) As String
    '//All datatable and dataset variables
    Dim dSet As DataSet
    Dim oDataTable As DataTable

    '//Displays the total number of ping Successes and Fails
    lblGoodPingTotal.Text = pingUp
    lblBadPingTotal.Text = pingDown
    lblTimeElapsed.Text = GlobalVariables.elapsedTime

    '//Sets the new dataset
    dSet = New DataSet()

    For Each fileName As String In rmNames

        oDataTable = New DataTable(fileName)
        '//Creating the columns and column names in code
        Dim Column1 As DataColumn = New DataColumn("Computer Name")
        Column1.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
        Dim Column2 As DataColumn = New DataColumn("Status")
        Column2.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
        Dim Column3 As DataColumn = New DataColumn("IP Address")
        Column3.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
        Dim Column4 As DataColumn = New DataColumn("Bytes Sent")
        Column4.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
        Dim Column5 As DataColumn = New DataColumn("Round Trip")
        Column5.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
        Dim Column6 As DataColumn = New DataColumn("TTL")
        Column6.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")

        '//Setting the columns for the generated datatable
        oDataTable.Columns.Add(Column1)
        oDataTable.Columns.Add(Column2)
        oDataTable.Columns.Add(Column3)
        oDataTable.Columns.Add(Column4)
        oDataTable.Columns.Add(Column5)
        oDataTable.Columns.Add(Column6)

        '//Setting the output file path
        resultFilePath = AppDir & "\data\output\" & fileName & ".txt"

        '//Setting the path to test for file existence
        fileExists = File.Exists(resultFilePath)

        If fileExists Then
            '//If the file exists the file is read into memory and the datatable has it's values assigned to a row
            Using sReader As New StreamReader(resultFilePath)

                While sReader.EndOfStream = False

                    '//New row created
                    Dim rowAdd As DataRow
                    rowAdd = oDataTable.NewRow()

                    '//New row has the data read and assigned to it
                    rowvalue = sReader.ReadLine()
                    cellvalue = rowvalue.Split(","c)

                    rowAdd.ItemArray = cellvalue

                    '//Datatabl gets the row of data assigned to it, one at a time
                    oDataTable.Rows.Add(rowAdd)

                End While

                sReader.Close()

            End Using

            '//Commits the changes to each datatable that's created
            oDataTable.AcceptChanges()

            '//Adds each datatable that's created to the Dataset for use in output
            dSet.Tables.Add(oDataTable)

        Else

            '//Error message just incase a output file wasn't generated for the selected room
            MsgBox("Error! The file for Room " & fileName & " is not found.", vbOKOnly = MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")

        End If

    Next

    '//Calling the sub-routine to output the date to the proper datagridview
    dataPrint(dSet)

End Sub

Private Sub dataPrint(iDataSet As DataSet)
    '//Variables cast for getting the Dataset and DataTable collections
    Dim datSet As DataSet = iDataSet
    Dim datTCollection As DataTableCollection = datSet.Tables
    '//Running the checks against the selected Dataset for Datatable names and information output
    For Each tbName As DataTable In datTCollection

        If tbName.TableName = "A1402" Then
            dgvA1402.DataSource = tbName
        ElseIf tbName.TableName = "A1532" Then
            dgvA1532.DataSource = tbName
        ElseIf tbName.TableName = "A1D038" Then
            dgvA1D038.DataSource = tbName
        ElseIf tbName.TableName = "A1D042" Then
            dgvA1D042.DataSource = tbName
        ElseIf tbName.TableName = "A1D043B" Then
            dgvA1D043B.DataSource = tbName
        ElseIf tbName.TableName = "A1E014A" Then
            dgvA1E014A.DataSource = tbName
        ElseIf tbName.TableName = "A1E036" Then
            dgvA1E036.DataSource = tbName
        ElseIf tbName.TableName = "A1E047C" Then
            dgvA1E047C.DataSource = tbName
        ElseIf tbName.TableName = "A1E047D" Then
            dgvA1E047D.DataSource = tbName
        ElseIf tbName.TableName = "A1E047F" Then
            dgvA1E047F.DataSource = tbName
        ElseIf tbName.TableName = "A1E047G" Then
            dgvA1E047G.DataSource = tbName
        ElseIf tbName.TableName = "A1E048" Then
            dgvA1E048.DataSource = tbName
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

I went through and re-did a lot of code. I took the core ideas of what I was trying to do and then refined them (not just in these code blocks either). That helped quite a bit, as it flowed the data better than my original code segments.

Anyways, on to the main answer, I found information on DataSets with DataTables and used the DataSet to store multiple DataTables with different Names. The names were provided from the read-in output files themselves. So all I needed to do after that, was search through the DataSet as a Collection and match up the names to the names of the TabPages and then output that respective tables data as the DataSource with the corresponding DataGridView.